# PHP - functions

Tags: php

I have two files (Ex-one.php,two.php). Some functions have same name in two files. A have another class file. I include that file(one.php,two.php) in two functions on class file. Then I create a object from class file in main php file. Then i call two functions in object(call functions in class file). when I call the function second time error occur ("Cannot **function_name**() (previously declared in **Previase include file name **")

how I **Solve this issue**

**one.php**

```
function a(){
   }
   function d(){}
```

**two.php**

```
    function a(){
  }
  function d(){}
```

**class file
-----------**

```
   class test{

 function one(){
  include_once("one.php")
 }

 function two(){
   include_once("two.php")
 }

}
```

**main file
---------**

```
    $test=new test();
$test->one();

$test->two();//(**in this line error occur**)
```

Comment: Namespaces if using a newer version of php

Comment: You cannot have two functions of the same name and load them both, period. Rename one of them. Using namespaces helps here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    namespace xxx {
         function A {}
    }
    namespace yyy{
         function A{}
    }
```

Not in the same file ofcourse. then to call them include and use `\xxx\A`

Php.net: [Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)